# Empty cell is not empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with empty cells. I want to skip empty cells, but I don't know, how to set IF condition. When I debug by F8, cell shows EMPTY, but IF condition go to THEN. Thanks for idea ;)

```
 For i = 5 To 76
    If i = 62 Or i = 63 Or i = 64 Then GoTo prechod

    Set myRange = actsheet.Range("V" & CStr(i))
    If Not IsEmpty(myRange.Value) Or Not IsError(myRange.Value) Or myRange.Value <> "" Or myRange.Value = Empty Then

    hodsheet.Range("A" & CStr(hity)).Value = myRange.Value
    hodsheet.Range("B" & CStr(hity)).Value = myRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
    hodsheet.Range("C" & CStr(hity)).Value = myRange.Offset(0, 7).Value
    hodsheet.Range("D" & CStr(hity)).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A7").Value
    hodsheet.Range("E" & CStr(hity)).Value = "nocni"



    hity = hity + 1
    End If
    prechod:
    Next i
```

Comment: `If not Len(trim(myRange.Value)) = 0 and Not IsError(myRange.Value) then`

Comment: Thank you, problem solved ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout got it right (like always) but maybe easier to understand `If Len(trim(myRange.Value)) > 0 and` ..., which means, if after trimming all the spaces, the greater than than `0`.

Comment: @ShaiRado LOL. I am not always right... I finally ended up posting an answer. I was feeling lazy but then i realised that it will not help future visitors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a cell is empty or not we can actually use `Len(Trim(Cell.Value))`.

The Microsoft Excel Visual Basic `LEN` function returns the length of the specified string. For Ex `Len("Sid")` will give you `3`

The Microsoft Excel Visual Basic `TRIM` function strips extra spaces from text, leaving only single spaces between words and no space characters at the start or end of the text. For Ex `TRIM("   SID   ")` will give you `SID`

By combining these two `Len(Trim(myRange.Value))` what we are doing is first trimming the cell value and then finding the length. So if the cell value is `"   "` then `Trim()` will remove the spaces and `LEN()` will give you `0`

And hence you need to use

```
If Not Len(Trim(myRange.Value)) = 0
```

Incorporating it in your code

```
If Not Len(Trim(myRange.Value)) = 0 And Not IsError(myRange.Value) Then
```

Comment: Excel's `TRIM` and VBA's `Trim` are different and work differently.  VBA's `Trim` only trims exterior spaces surrounding the whole sentence, while *Excel's* `TRIM` **also** trims extra spaces between different words in the sentence. The answer references Excel's `TRIM` but the suggested code actually uses VBA'a `Trim`. To use Excel's version, use `Application.Trim`.

Comment: But of course, this difference is not relevant to the OP's case, where we only want to check for empty strings. Just wanted to highlight the two possibilities, one might need one of them or the other.

Comment: @A.S.H: I was referring to VBA's trim above. :)

Answer (score -2):

At first all the select from input data and go to replace option, replace with -, 0 or any character which will not effect your output

Comment: then that sheet must be data protected, password must be required. if you know the password go to Review tab and select unprotect sheet